# Galaxy S5 Active home button - weird long press behavior

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, bugs, att, home-button

I've got an S5 Active on AT&T. After the latest update, my home button started registering almost any press as a "long press." Does anyone have an idea of how to fix or mitigate this problem? Also, if anyone else has experienced the same thing, please let me know as I'd like to think I'm not crazy!

Answer (score 2):

The good news: you're not losing your mind.  The even-better news: there seems to be a solution.

Head on over to [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/215325/Home+button+doesn%27t+go+home) and take a look at their thread.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found while waiting for an update to fix the update is to turn off auto updates if it's on, and uninstall all updates to the Google application, restoring that app to factory. Hoping there's a better fix soon so I can turn auto updates back on.